# Does $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}=0$ imply that $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}$ cannot be finite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we have two functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that
$$\hspace{1cm}\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow -\infty}g(y)=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow -\infty}f(y)=0 \tag{1}$$
Moreover, we know that
$$\hspace{1cm}\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}=0 \tag{2}$$
which I interpret as saying "g goes to zero faster than $f$".

Do (1), (2) imply that 
$$
\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)} 
$$
cannot be a finite number? If this is not true, can you make a counterexample?

Comment: The answer is YES.

Comment: Suppose that the final limit were a finite number $L$. Then what would $\frac{\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} 1}{\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}} $ be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is not finite; if it were finite, say $\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}=L$, then this would imply that
$$0\cdot L=\left(\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right)\left(\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}\right)=\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\left(\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}\right)=\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}1=1.$$

Comment: Thanks, at the beginning do you mean "yes, it is not finite"?

Comment: Indeed I do, I have edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion is true.

$\lim_{y\to-\infty} \frac{f(y)}{g(y)} = 0$ means that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists M > 0$ such that $\left|\frac{f(y)}{g(y)}\right| < \epsilon$ whenever $y < -M$.

So, it follows that $\left|\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right| > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, whenever $y < -M$. Thus, $\lim_{y\to-\infty}\left|\frac{g(y)}{f(y)}\right| = \infty$.